# Delete all related records Yii2 using ActiveRecord

Tags: php, eloquent, yii2

In Laravel i can do something like this:

```
$product->options()->delete() // Using Eloquent query builder
```

Is it possible to delete related models using `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no dedicated shortcut for this - to delete all related records you need to use foreach and delete each record separately:

```
foreach ($product->options as $option) {
    $option->delete();
}
```

There is a official package (still WIP) which may bring support for collections and more convenient/efficient way of deleting all related records: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-collection